# matplotlib using different default color and interface

Tags: python, matplotlib

Recently I format my laptop (using Xfce) and make a fresh install of python2.7 and matplotlib (2.0.0). But the plots, as well as the interface are appearing different compared to the installation in my desktop (gnome3, matplotlib 1.5.3).

Is it due to change of version or am I missing something? I have tcl, tk 8.6.6, python2-matplotlib-tk and python2-tkinter installed.

If it is due to change of version, is there any way to go back to old style?

> New installation (change in default line color)

[image]

> Old Installation

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's because of the version change in matplotlib 2.0

https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html

> A ‘classic’ style sheet is provided so reverting to the 1.x default values is a single line of python:
>   `mpl.style.use('classic')`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('classic')
plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Haiku. I guess there is no way to change the interface. I like those old color buttons compared to the new black buttons.

Comment: @Sumit Yes the plot coloring system changes but those icons won't change with this. You can also customize the icons but I think that needs the change in matplotlib's user interface.

Answer (score 2):

With the release of matplotlib 2.0 there have been [a lot of changes](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html) being made to the interface as well as to the plotting style.

The images of the matplotlib buttons are stored in

```
Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
```

inside your python directory. You can replace them with the old images, if you like, or even design your own buttons.

The old buttons should be available [in the 1.5.3 release](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/releases/tag/v1.5.3).